# Symfony 3.1 Listener with access to database

Tags: symfony

I have a config table with a 'web_enabled' key, when true I want to show the route requested but when false I want to show a 'Site in maintenance' page. Obviously this check has to be performed before any route action.

I have been reading about Events and Listeners but I don't see how to implement the access to the doctrine and template.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I implemented finally, differs from the proposed by Alsatian because I don't use a parameter in the service.yml. Is just a question of taste, nothing else.

in app/config/services.yml

```
services:
app.request_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@templating"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelController }
```

in src/AppBundle/EventListener/RequestListener.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RequestListener
{
    private $em;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct($em, $templating)
    {
       $this->em = $em;
       $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function onKernelController(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ( !$this->configKey = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Config')->getconfig('web_enabled') )
            $event->setResponse($this->templating->renderResponse('default/construction.html.twig'));

    }
}
```

and in src/AppBundle/Repository/ConfigRepository.php explaining the getconfig method:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

class ConfigRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getconfig( $config_name )
    {
        $config = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT p.config_value FROM AppBundle:Config p WHERE p.config_name = :config_name')
        ->setParameter('config_name', $config_name)
        ->getResult();
        if (sizeof($config)){
            return $config[0]['config_value'];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah  ? web_installed was an entity property ? Didn't undestand it so ;)

Comment: No worries, with your code I get the idea and others with the same question will have the two solutions, with a service parameter and with an entity.     :-).

Answer (score 0):

You have just to inject both EntityManager and Templating in your listener :

Definition as service :

```
# src/AppBundle/Ressources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.request_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
        arguments: ["%web_enabled%","@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@templating"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Listener :

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RequestListener
{
    private $configKey;
    private $em;
    private $templating;

    public __construct($configKey, $em, $templating)
    {
        $this->configKey = $configKey;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if(!$this->configKey){
            $var = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyEntity')->findOne(1);

            $event->setResponse($this->templating->renderResponse('my_template.html.twig',array('var'=>$var));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelController() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent given

Comment: That's what I get. I don't see any reference to FilterControllerEvent.??? This lost me.

Comment: Thanks Alsatian. I'm going to post here the solution I implemented with your assessment.